# How do I get a basic spec file to work with rpmbuild?

Tags: rpm, specfile

I installed rpmlint and rpmdevtools.  I used rpmdevtools to create a template of a .spec file.  I modified the spec file so it will install cfengine.   I ran rpmlint on the spec file, and I saw no warnings or errors.  I then tried to run the specfile for real, but it failed.  Here is the command I ran:

```
$ rpmbuild -ba newpackage.spec
```

Here is what I saw:

```
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.wNGgcV
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/ec2-user//BUILD
+ cd /home/ec2-user/BUILD
+ rm -rf Propulsion-1
+ /usr/bin/tar -xf -
+ /usr/bin/gzip -dc /home/ec2-user/SOURCES/cfengine-3.6.5.tar.gz
+ STATUS=0
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ cd Propulsion-1
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.wNGgcV: line 35: cd: Propulsion-1: No such file or directory
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.wNGgcV (%prep)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.wNGgcV (%prep)
```

The file above on line 35 has this:

cd 'Propulsion-1'

The "Propulsion" name comes from the .spec file.  Evidently, the single quotes, hyphen and 1 come from the rpm-build command processing.

What should I do to not have an RPM build error?  I want my spec file to work for the installation of cfengine.

Here is the spec file:

```
Name:  Propulsion
Version: 1
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:  First time

License:        GNU
#URL:
Source0: http://s3.amazonaws.com/cfengine.package-repos/tarballs/cfengine-3.6.5.tar.gz

BuildRequires: gettext
# Requires:

%description
This is a test.

%prep
%setup -q


%build
%configure
make %{?_smp_mflags}


%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
%make_install


%files
%doc


%changelog
```

Comment: If you are trying to package cfengine, why have you named this packge Propulsion?

Comment: Is the name not arbitrary?  I tried "cfengine."  But that didn't help me.

Comment: There is a lot to learn here. I suggest you start with [How to create an RPM package](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is happening because `%setup` is actually a macro that when expanded, will try to un-tar your source and `cd` into the source directory.

If the source directory in the tarball differs from the name of the package, you need to set `-n`, like this:

`%setup -n cfengine-3.6.5`

In your case, this should work, because when you extract `cfengine-3.6.5.tar.gz` you get a directory named `cfengine-3.6.5` -- and rpmbuild is expecting `Propulsion-1` based on your package name and version.

You can read more about the setup macro [here](http://rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/s1-rpm-inside-macros.html) and [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package#SPEC_file_sections_explained).

Comment: This definitely helped me progress.  I'm going to mark it as the answer because this question is getting long.  Michael said that there was a lot to learn.  I agree.